# How to generate a set of random number with two sum

Tags: javascript, math, random, nlp

I'm trying to use javascript to implement the inside-outside algorithm of PCFG. But I have porblem generating a set of random data.

Assume that I need 10 random number, I need:

1. the sum of first 5 number is 1 and sum the last 5 number also 1;
2. the sum of the 3rd, 4th, 5th, 8th, 9th 10th is 1;

I have no idea how may i do this.

Currently, i could only implement one of the two point.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this page (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)

```
Math.random();
```

will give yo a number between 0 and 1.

Taken that you have no constraint on the number values and that you could only implement one of the two point, one idea could be to generate 4 numbers (n1 to n4) between 0 and 0.25.
You will have very few change to get 4 times 0.25 = 1.
Your fifth number will be just 1 - (n1+n2+n3+n4).

Now how to get a random number between 0 and 0.25 ? Maybe divide by 4 Math.random() ? (careful of division by 0 !)

The same idea could be applied to your second problem with 6 numbers, by divided by 6 (to get each number between 0 and 1/6 and last the reminder to get 1).

**EDIT:**

Check this and improve it !

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stackoverflow question 31336708</title>
    </head>

        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                // Solve rule #2
                var n3=Math.random()/6;
                var n4=Math.random()/6;
                var n5=Math.random()/6;
                var n8=Math.random()/6;
                var n9=Math.random()/6;
                var n10=1-(n3+n4+n5+n8+n9);     // filling the cup for rule #1

                // limit case for rule #1       : n3=n4=n5 = 1/6 and n8=n9 = 0.   n10 = 0.5     ==> spread 0.5 on n6 and n7 ==> random/4
                // other limit case for rule #1 : n3=n4=n5 = 0   and n8=n9 = 1/6. n10 = 4/6=2/3 ==> spread 1/3 on n6 and n7 ==> random/6
                // ==> cut the apple in two ==> use random/5 for n2
                var n2=Math.random()/5;
                var n1=1-(n2+n3+n4+n5);             // filling the cup for rule #2

                var R1=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5;
                var R2=n3+n4+n5+n8+n9+n10;

                //checking :
                alert("Checking rule #1 = <"+R1+"> with\n n1="+n1+"\n n2="+n2+"\n n3="+n3+"\n n4="+n4+"\n n5="+n5);
                alert("Checking rule #2 = <"+R1+"> with\n n3="+n3+"\n n4="+n4+"\n n5="+n5+"\n n8="+n8+"\n n9="+n9+"\n n10="+n10);
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it in two steps

1. First, item#2, generate 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10 random number summed to 1. For that you could use Dirichlet distribution (or degenerate gammavariate). If you don't know how to do it, just ask.
2. Obviously, now back to #1. First, you generate two random numbers such that they sum up to 1 - (3+4+5).

   `x1 = sample in the range [0...1-(3+4+5)]`

   `x2 = 1-(3+4+5) - x1`

Second, same approach for 6,7,8,9,10

```
y1 = sample in the range [0...1-(8+9+10)]
y2 = 1-(8+9+10) - y1
```